How to make a dashboard which compares data of 2 different reports like comparing monthly data of FY 2023 with monthly data of FY 2024
I want to compare 2 yr data on monthly basis in a dashboard
I am not able to generate a comparison dashboard
I have 2 different reports

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you would need one report of FY 2023 and FY 2024 data then summarize by year or month to get the years on different bars. Then if you want to get fancy you can use report summarizes to compare the groupings to get a % change if you want that.
A singular dashboard component cannot look at 2 reports it's one report per component, however you can use the same report multiple times creating multiple components in one dashboard. So in theory you can have the left column be F23 numbers and the right column be F24 numbers. Or mix and match.
